# Is there way to notify user to wait WebView to load images

Tags: android, android-webview

I have WebView in my activity and I need to load some local string ( html ) in that webview. Problem is that local html contains images from remoted servers so it needs time to download and show. Is there way to notify user to wait, like spinning dialog or something ? How to notify user to wait content ?

Answer (score 2):

There is not built-in function for doing what you need.

However, you can set a [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) on [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) (see [`webView.setWebViewClient()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebViewClient%28android.webkit.WebViewClient%29)) and override the methods [`onPageStarted()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageStarted%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29) and [`onPageFinished()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29). In this way you can show a [`ProgressDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) or other progress indicator (use a [`RotateAnimation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html) for example) when the page has started loading and dismiss it later when the page has finished loading.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
  public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
    //show progress indicator
  }

  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
    //hide progress indicator
  }
});
```

Comment: Problem with this approach is that it breaks the WebView functionality, e.g, opening pages outside it. You'd have to set the other `WebViewClient` functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that in your html page using [css](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/css-xhtml/css3-loading-spinners-without-images/) or [javascript](http://andrewpeace.com/javascript-css-loading-screen.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could set a [webviewCLient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) to the webview and you will get callback onPageFinished.

Answer (score 0):

ts working fine on all devices Use this link :- [Load Web View ProgressDialog](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/31/load-webview-with-progressdialog/)